# Error: The import java.nio.file.Files cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

Java newbie here,

Using jdk1.8.0_05, I seem to be unable to resolve the java.nio.file.Files class

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
```

with the following error:

> The import java.nio.file.Files cannot be resolved

All other java.nio.file.* Classes (Path, Paths, FileSystem, etc.) seem to resolve just fine.  Based on other answers I've made sure of the following:

1. Java build path set to JRE System Library jre8 for the project
2. Set workspace compiler compliance level to 1.7, as high as it goes

I'm using eclipse 3.7.2.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try to 'refresh' your project and then 'clean up'?

Comment: try to restart your IDE too.

Comment: Sorry I'm new, do you mean file -> Refresh, then project -> Clean?  I just tried that and nothing seems to have changed.... and tried the restart to no avail.  Thanks though!

Comment: Are you sure that the "jre8" JRE points to a 1.8 (or 1.7) JRE? That class did exist before 1.7. And why such an old version of Eclipse?

Comment: The only versions of the jre that are on my computer are 1.7 and 1.8, so I think I am good there.  As for your other question, that is the eclipse version "approved" for our network.

Comment: Does it work with the Java 1.7 JRE? Eclipse 3.7 doesn't support any of the new Java 8 features so you don't gain much using it.

Comment: right click project / Java Compiler / make sure Compiler compliance level is 1.7 or 1.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely something to do with the version of eclipse (3.7.2) that I was using.  Someone gave me their copy of android developer tools and the problem went away.

So... Update your eclipse if you see this.

Answer (score 3):

> Files cannot be resolved
>   Paths cannot be resolved

FIX :

```
import java.nio.file.*;
```