# java.nio.file not working even with JDK 1.7 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

In a programe,

```
import java.nio.file.*;
```

Gives error - `The import java.nio.file cannot be resolved`

Following other threads, I changed JDK Compliance Level to 1.7, also added

```
-vm
/home/user/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java
```

to eclipse.ini

Eclipse -> About -> Installation details has following lines -

java.home=/home/user/jdk1.7.0_79/jre

java.library.path=/home/user/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/i386/server:/home/user/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/i386:/home/user/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib

java, javac versions -

user$ ~/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
user$ ~/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
user$ ~/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javac -version
javac 1.7.0_79

How should I correctly import `java.nio.file.*`?

Comment: You probably mean `import java.nio.file.*;`? [`java.nio.file`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) is a package, not a class and can therefore not be imported.

Comment: Isnt the Java home just - /home/user/jdk1.7.0_79 ? I guess you added jre as well to it. Can you change the java.home to point to  /home/user/jdk1.7.0_79 and try again ?

Comment: @KalyanChavali I don't know. It came by default. Even if I add `-Djava.home=/path/to/jdk` to ini and restart eclipse it still shows the jre path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898554/error-the-import-java-nio-file-files-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: The JRE/JDK Eclipse use for compiling projects can be set in the Preferences dialog -> Java -> Installed JREs

Comment: Then what about in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed Jre's ? What is the java version set here?

Comment: @Robert It's set at `/home/user/jdk1.7.0_79/`

Comment: @KalyanChavali  It's set at `/home/user/jdk1.7.0_79/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it!

Even after doing all the recommended things it wasn't working. Finally saw a setting in another thread that I hadn't tried till now.

> Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library
>   -> JRE System Library -> Select Workspace Default (jdk 1.7*)

Done.

So even when eclipse installation details configuration may show all the correct numbers, we still have to explicitly add 1.7 library from project properties.